# Martingale $X_n \to \infty$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, martingales

Construct a martingale $X_n$ such that $X_n \to \infty $  a.s.

I have trouble coming up with such an example and prove it. Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1:=0$, $\ X_n:=X_{n-1}-(n-1)+Y_{n}$, where $Y_n$ is independent, $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ measurable and $P(Y_n=0)=1/n$, $P(Y_n=n)=1-1/n$. Then $E[Y_n]=n-1$, so $E[X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=X_{n-1}$. Since $X_n\rightarrow\infty$ is a 0-1 event, we just need to show that it occurs with positive probability to conclude $X_n\rightarrow\infty$ almost surely. If $Y_n=n$, then $X_n=X_{n-1}+1$, so clearly

$$P(X_n\rightarrow\infty)\geq \prod_{n=2}^\infty (1-1/n)\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1-1/n)^n=e^{-1}>0$$

Comment: What is your probability space and $F_n$?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_n$ is a filtration, say induced by the joint product measure $(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2\cdots, X_n\leq x_n)$. The only thing that matters is the induced measure on the real line, in other words $\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq x)$.

Comment: $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-1/n)=(1-\frac{1}{1})\prod_{n=2}^\infty (1-1/n)=0 * 0=0$

Comment: I mean that $\prod_{n=k}^\infty (1-1/n)=0$ for any $k$ (the second inequality is incorrect). So, you need other argument here.

Comment: Actually, this can be redefined as $P(Y_n'=-n+1)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $P(Y_n'=1)=1-\frac{1}{n}$. so that $X_n=X_{n-1}+Y_n'$. However, $\sum P(Y_n'=-n+1)=\infty$ and $P(Y_n'=-n+1 \text{  i.o.})=1$. Hence, it's not obvious that this martingale converges to $\infty$.